# How to remove child elements based on some conditions like tag,

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know how to remove child elements of a parent with some conditions like tag, class, attribute....

```
<div class="parent">
  <a class="child_a" ...
  <div class="middle" ...
  <input class='child_last" ...
</div>
```

please share your code!

Comment: please write your code as much as possible to make sure what your problem is later

Answer (score 2):

You can use these conditions

```
 let parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0];
 parent.childNodes.forEach(c=>{
 if(c.className  == 'child_a'){
    parent.removeChild(c);
 }

 if(c.tagName  == 'INPUT'){
    parent.removeChild(c);
 }

 if(c.tagName != undefined && c.getAttribute('src') == 'test'){
    parent.removeChild(c);
 }
```

});

```js
let parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0];
  parent.childNodes.forEach(c=>{
     if(c.className  == 'child_a'){
  parent.removeChild(c);
  }
 
  if(c.tagName  == 'INPUT'){
  parent.removeChild(c);
  }
  
  if(c.tagName != undefined && c.getAttribute('src') == 'test'){
     parent.removeChild(c);
  }
  });
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a class="child_a">A</a>
  <div class="middle">DIV</div>
  <input class="child_last" />
  
  <img src="test" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution to that problem would be to get the `parent` element, make a query selection in order to get it's `children`, transform `children` into an array an then iterate over it, removing one `child` at a time.

So let's suppose I want to filter `parent`'s children to get only elements with the `.target` class:

```
const parent = document.getElementById('#parent')
const children = parent.querySelectorAll('.target')

[...children].forEach(child => parent.removeChild(child)
```

You can also abstract this to have a generic function that receives a given `parent` and a set of `children`:

```
const removeChildren = (parent, ...children) => children.forEach(child => parent.removeChild(child))
// ...
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');
const targets = parent.querySelectorAll('.target');
removeChildren(parent, ...targets);
```

It's important to use `forEach()` instead of `map()` because `removeChild()` actually returns a value - the very node you just removed. I don't thing it's interesting to return such and so prefer to return nothing.